# Can't load pdb symbols for one particular JS file in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

Trying to figure this one out despite all the other posts for this question...

My .pdb file is loading into the .bin folder and running for all my pages except one js file where I can't get the breakpoints to hit while debugging in IE.

I usually try clearing the IE cache, restarting Visual Studio, even restarting my machine. None worked! I tried updating VS because there was an update available.

I thought it might be because I added a reference to a NuGet package for pagination, but I tried removing the references and deleting the code in HTML that references it. Still can't hit the breakpoints in that one particular JS file.

I know the JS file is running because I see the dynamically loaded content from the file on the page.

What else can I check?

Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10. C# MVC application

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'm not sure why this worked, but I reset all the IE setting in the advanced tab.
Usually I just clear all the browser data and that works.

Answer (score 0):

It probably was loading an older cached version of the the .js file. If you have problems again try to clear all the cached files for the application you are debugging C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I don't have that path on my Windows 10 machine. I have C:\Users but no AppData in that folder

Comment: AppData is a hidden folder. In Windows Explorer View>Options. Select the View tab and under Hidden files and folders select Show hidden files, folders, and drives. Click the button Apply to Folders. The full path should be c:\Users\<your user id>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache.